# Scraping of scant search results on a website JSON and Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Goal: I would like to export these results from a zip code with the company name and address from this GAF website database. The last error it gave me was a df error in a Jupyter interpreter. The output of the search isn't as clean as other databases I have used. Any tips would be helpful. Would like to extract the phone number as well, seems you have to click on the record then hover of the phone number for that.

```
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://www.gaf.com/en-us/roofing-contractors/residential?postalcode=84103', headers = headers)
p = re.compile(r'PRELOADED_STATE__ = (.*?);')
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
results = [(item['contractor-result-card__name'], ' '.join([item['contractor-result-card__address']] for item in data['contractor-results']['results']
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Business Name', 'Address',])
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: I don't see `PRELOADED_STATE__` in source code of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get contractor names and addresses, you can do:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.gaf.com/en-us/roofing-contractors/residential?postalcode=84103'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser' )

all_data = []
for contractor in soup.select('[data-contractors]'):
    data = json.loads(contractor['data-contractors'])
    all_data.append({'Business Name': data[0]['name'], 'Address': contractor.find_next('address').contents[0] + ', ' + data[0]['location']})


df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Prints:

```
                              Business Name                                     Address
0             Infinity Roofing & Siding Inc   50 W Broadway Ste 300, Salt Lake City, UT
1                          Lifetime Roofing  890 W Center St Ste 5, North Salt Lake, UT
2                       The Roof Doctor LLC   2854 S Redwood Rd Ste C4, West Valley, UT
3                          Fortress Roofing          5975 S Stratler St # B, Murray, UT
4                               RoofTek LLC                8490 S State St, Midvale, UT
5  Integrated Roofing Solutions & Consultin           14043 S Emmeline Dr, Herriman, UT
6                            Legacy Roofing        570 E 1700 S Ste 201, Clearfield, UT
7          Parrish Construction Company Inc             1265 E 300 N, American Fork, UT
```

And saves `data.csv`:

[image]